# Populating UserProfile at User registration

Tags: django

I'm trying to populate a User profile field at user registration (I've read that this is not recommended however is required for my app)

model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def create(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create, sender=User)
```

view.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/home')
else:
    form = RegForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'home/registration_form.html', args)
```

form.py

```
class RegForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    twitter = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = (
            'username',
            'twitter',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.userprofile.twitter = self.cleaned_data['twitter']

       if commit:
           user.save()

       return user
```

Currently, I'm getting the error "User has no userprofile"

(first time using Django, sorry if this is a silly question, I couldn't find anything that helped online)

Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  298.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: app_userprofile.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/IS/Desktop/Project/website/app/views.py" in register
  37.             form.save()

File "/Users/IS/Desktop/Project/website/app/form.py" in save
  42.             profile.save()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in **exit**
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  298.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /app/register/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_userprofile.user_id

Comment: I don't see a UserProfile field in your code. Where is it defined?

Comment: @farooq it is the automatic reverse relation for the one to one field from UserProfile to User.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you read that you shouldn't do this; it's fine.

Since you're creating the User, you also need to create the UserProfile.

```
user = super(RegForm, self).save(commit=False)
profile = UserProfile(user=user, twitter=form.cleaned_data["twitter"]
if commit:
    user.save()
    profile.save()
```

But now you've done this, you should remove that signal. You don't need it.

Note, you don't need to set username, first_name or last_name, the form will do that for you.

Comment: After making these changes I got the error "Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_userprofile.user_id
"

Comment: Hmm can you show the full traceback (as an edit to the question)?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong, this should work. Did you definitely have the user save first, and both of them within the if block?

Comment: Still getting the same error, I removed profile.save() and everything else is working as expected. I believe there could be an issue with the way I've set up my register function (added above)